# Should you commit Nx's migrations.json file?

Tags: migration, commit, gitignore, nomachine-nx

I've used the nx migrate command that generated a `migrations.json` file at the root of my project. I've ran the migrations and they were successful.

I've committed the changes done by the migration and now considering if there's a point in keeping the `migrations.json` file, as its changes are already applied and committed.

I'm thinking of removing the file from the repo or even gitignoring it.
Will removing the file affect future migrations in any way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, do remove this file. After the migrations have been run, nx no longer needs `migrations.json`.

It says so in step 3 of the migrations docs, https://nx.dev/using-nx/updating-nx#step-3-cleaning-up

> Step 3: Cleaning up
>
> After you run all the migrations, you can remove migrations.json and commit any outstanding changes.

Comment: ...however the same paragraph also warns: "You may want to keep the migrations.json until every branch that was created before the migration has been merged. Leaving the migrations.json in place allows devs to run nx migrate --run-migrations to apply the same migration process to their newly merged code as well."